# Two-Factor authentication bypass

Tags: account-security, multi-factor, access-token, hardware-token, account-lockout

I use two-factor authentication where possible, I was always under the impression that not only it prevents brute-force attacks, but makes it safer to use my accounts in untrusted environments.

I always relied on a fact that sites offer me option to invalidate active sessions and in most cases notify me of changes made to my account.

But recently, I noticed, that on some sites, I'm able to add/remove or disable 2nd factor authentication without confirming the change with 2nd factor. Which would mean that when I login on a compromised device and my session cookie is stolen,
then nothing prevents attacker to take over my account, they could simply add their passkey/token and delete mine.

Most notably I tried this on **microsoft.com** and **google.com** accounts.

Is there a way to prevent this kind of account takeover with stolen session?

Is there some technical/procedural reason which would explain the lack of re-authentication to confirm changes in security settings on side of these login providers?